# How to invoke utility omeld (oitnb) from git

Tags: python, git, code-formatting, oitnb

oitnb (https://pypi.org/project/oitnb/) looks like a combination of the good parts of yapf and black. The author claims it tackles the issue of comparing old revisions (before formatting) with revisions committed after formatting using a utility named omeld. The example on integrating that utiltiy is for mercurial, and we are using git.

I have tried to register the omeld utility with

```
get config --global diff.tool /usr/local/bin/omeld
```

but did get things to work, `git` keeps telling it doesn't know about omeld.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use the alias shown below, but **before you do so** you should upgrade to `oitnb>0.1.3` or use the following replacement for `omeld.py`:

```
import sys
import os


def main():
    # print('omeld:', os.getcwd(), sys.argv[1:])
    assert len(sys.argv) == 3, 'omeld: expecting two arguments'
    runs = 0
    for idx, arg in enumerate(sys.argv[1:]):
        assert os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]), f'omeld: parameter {idx}, cannot find "{arg}"'
        rp = os.path.realpath(arg)
        # check if you are on a temporary directory, so there is less chance to screw up
        if rp.startswith('/tmp/') or rp.startswith('/var/tmp/'):
            runs += 1
            os.system('oitnb -q ' + rp)
    if runs > 0:
        os.system('meld ' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
    else:
        print('could not run oitnb on "{}" or "{}"'.format(*sys.argv[1:]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

because the version distributed with `oitnb=0.1.3` can format files in your source directory if you compare on old version against the current state. In `git` this seems to happen more often (it seems optimized to not create a temporary file, even e.g. if the current version of a file has not changed since the commit of the second revision).

The alias:

```
alias gomeld='git difftool --extcmd=/path/to/omeld -y'
```

I have looked at changing the config, but have not got that to work either.

Comment: I posted another question on oitnb, can you look at it?